# Change directory where get_header(), get_footer() and get_sidebar() look for templates

Tags: templates, sidebar, headers, footer

I'm creating my own theme framework, and I want to organize my code, separating the partials files from the pages.

But I want to do that and still use the native functions `get_header()`, `get_footer()` and `get_sidebar()`.

How can I change this functions to look for the templates on the directory `partials/` instead of the theme's root directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution, use [`get_template_part()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).

For example:

```
get_template_part( 'partials/footer' );
```

Which would get the `footer.php` inside the `partials/` directory.

Another example:

```
get_template_part( 'partials/footer', 'home' );
```

Which would get the `footer-home.php` inside the `partials/` directory.

One more example:

```
get_template_part( 'partials/footer/blog' );
```

Which would get the `blog.php` inside the `partials/footer/` directory.

Comment: It works fine, thanks! But I got a problem with WooCommerce. The problem is that WooCommerce uses get_header/sidebar/footer on their templates, and since I change the directory of those files, WP gives me error that says that `theme without header/footer/sidebar is obsolete since version 3.0`. Do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: If you implement a custom template structure, then you should do the same with the [WooCommerce templates by customizing them too](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). Unfortunately `get_footer()` isn't very customizable here and if there is some smart solution, then I don't know it. The problem lies in the usage of `get_footer()` - and `get_header`/`get_sidebar` - itself, because it checks for the existence of the file in the theme root and if not available gives you the error and loads `wp-includes/theme-compat/footer.php`.  @vinigarcia87

Comment: It's sad that we can't just hook the defaulf wp functions. :S
Thanks for your answer, was very helpful!